Unsure if there's a need using synchronized with concurrentMap
I have reviewed an implementation of map of maps in java and seen an excessive use of synchronized:
public class NestedMap<K1, K2, V> {
  private Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  
  synchronized public V put(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v) {
    Map<K2, V> map = data.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    return map.put(k2, v);
  }

  synchronized public V get(K1 k1, K2 k2) {
    Map<K2, V> map = data.get(k1);
    if (null == map) return null;
    return map.get(k2);
  }

  synchronized public V remove(K1 k1, K2 k2) {
    Map<K2, V> map = data.get(k1);
    if (null == map) return null;
    return map.remove(k2);
  }

  synchronized public void remove(K1 k1) {
    data.remove(k1);
  }

  synchronized public Map<K2, V> get(K1 k1) {
    return this.data.get(k1);
  }

  synchronized public V computeIfAbsent(K1 k1, K2 k2, Function<? super K2, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
    Map<K2, V> map = data.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    return map.computeIfAbsent(k2, mappingFunction);
  }

  synchronized public V putIfAbsent(K1 k1, K2 k2, V v) {
    Map<K2, V> map = data.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    return map.putIfAbsent(k2, v);
  }

  synchronized public List<V> getAll() {
    List<V> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map<K2, V> map : data.values()) {
      for (V v : map.values()) {
        result.add(v);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  synchronized public List<V> getAll(K1 k1) {
    List<V> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<K2, V> map = data.get(k1);
    if (null == map) return result;
    result.addAll(map.values());
    return result;
  }

  synchronized public void clear() {
    data.clear();
  }

  public Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> getData() {
    return data;
  }
}

As my knowledge, synchronized on a method locks itself to enforce only one thread can access it at the same time. But negativity would be the downside of the performance.
I have even pasted it to copilot and it suggested removal of all synchronized, but I think it is wrong.
However, I believe not all methods require synchronized to enforce atomics.
Not to mention remove and get, although put contains two atomic operations, I don't think there is a must to use synchronized for all methods. But I was told it is necessary.
To enforce consistence, I would prefer synchronized on this class' caller instead.
Could you commit for this class or idea of optimization as well?

Apart from removing synchronized, which are indeed unnecessary, I'd also highly reconsider your getData method. It returns the map directly which allows external code to modify it. Nothing prevents anyone from putting a HashMap or TreeMap in there. The least you should do is wrap it in Collections.unmodifiableMap. That still allows all nested maps to be modified, but those are thread-safe.

None of those synchronized is needed in this case.
BTW synchronized on this is bad practice.

Consider there are two threads calling the method remove(k1, k2) and remove(k1) respectively, there would be a case null pointer exception occurred at map.remove(k2); . Because remove(k1) may happened after if (null == map) return null;

@EthanAlef Don't see where is NPE can happens. map is check for null before access.

@EthanAlef talex is right, map is a local variable that doesn't change anymore.

Ah yeah I tested:

Map<K2, V> map = data.get(k1);
data.remove(k1);
The map variable still holds a reference to the inner map, even though it has been removed from the outer map.

Therefore, the map variable is not null, and map.remove(k2) does not throw a NullPointerException.
I mistake the reference is freed

I can understand that talex
synchronized on this means locking the whole object.It is consider a bad practice because exposing the lock to external code can lead to potential deadlocks or other synchronization issues. If necessary we would rather use block-level locking.

@EthanAlef yes.
